# How to use sum function in pandas from the table present below

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count, sum

I am trying to add all the rows so it can be seen like this, it must add only (1) in Uptime, (2) in Downtime, (3) in PM.

```
`df = DataFrame({'A' : ['a','b','c','d','e'], 'B' : [1,1,3, 2,1],'C':[1,1,2,3,1],'D':[1,1,1,2,3].'E':[1,2,3,1,1]})
    df

 A B C D E Uptime Downtime P.M
 a 1 1 1 1   4
 b 1 1 1 2   3      2 
 c 3 2 1 3   1      2       6
 d 2 3 2 1   1      4       3
 e 1 1 3 1   3              3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with list comprehension:

```
df[['Uptime', 'Downtime', 'P.M.']] = pd.concat(
    [(df.eq(x)*x).sum(1) for x in range(1, 4)], 1)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  Uptime  Downtime  P.M.
0  a  1  1  1  1       4         0     0
1  b  1  1  1  2       3         2     0
2  c  3  2  1  3       1         2     6
3  d  2  3  2  1       1         4     3
4  e  1  1  3  1       3         0     3
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this works?Thanks

Comment: @chinnavenkat Sure, we basically iterate `x` from 1 to 3 and on each step `df.eq(x)` gives us True/False for each cell of the `df`, which we then multiply by `x` (so True becomes `x` and False becomes zero) and sum. This gives us 3 separate arrays, which we then `concat` and assign to new columns in our dataframe ('Uptime', 'Downtime', 'P.M.')

Comment: Thank You soo much for your explanation, I had been trying to post this like for 2 days, I had been having issues posting queries here, I am new in stack overflow as well as pandas, still thanks a lot.

Comment: @chinnavenkat Great, and welcome to SO then :) If the answer helped, can you please mark it as accepted?

Comment: sure will do, just trying to look for it

Comment: @chinnavenkat There should be a check mark that you can click, see this for example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: done, the code was that a pre-defined one |  a user-defined. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Try with `where` and `sum(1)`:

```
df = df.set_index('A')
cols = df.columns
df['Uptime'] = df[cols].where(df[cols].eq(1), 0).sum(1)
df['Downtime'] = df[cols].where(df[cols].eq(2), 0).sum(1)
df['P.M'] = df[cols].where(df[cols].eq(3), 0).sum(1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
  B  C  D  E  Uptime  Downtime  P.M
A                                   
a  1  1  1  1       4         0    0
b  1  1  1  2       3         2    0
c  3  2  1  3       1         2    6
d  2  3  2  1       1         4    3
e  1  1  3  1       3         0    3
```

Comment: When I Used this code, it gives me an error saying that all my columns are not in the index

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
m_1 = df == 1
m_2 = df == 2
m_3 = df == 3

df["Uptime"] = (m_1).sum(axis=1).astype(int)
df["Downtime"] = (m_2 * 2).sum(axis=1).astype(int)
df["P.M"] = (m_3 * 3).sum(axis=1).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  Uptime  Downtime  P.M
0  a  1  1  1  1       4         0    0
1  b  1  1  1  2       3         2    0
2  c  3  2  1  3       1         2    6
3  d  2  3  2  1       1         4    3
4  e  1  1  3  1       3         0    3
```